# How to track a variable from a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an extension for Google Chrome and one thing I need is to track a variable from a website. For example, if I wanted to know whether a user is logged in or not for Facebook, they might have a variable called loggedIn which is set as true or false. How can I get the value of this variable and use it, if it is possible? I realize this is a vague question, but I just want to know if there is a function in JavaScript that can be used to track a variable's value from a published website.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is cookies. the browser doesn't track logins or any such specifics by itself, but cookies are probably something you can use to get the functionality you want.

Comment: you want to check it via js api or any continues time interval

Comment: Sorry, I don't entirely understand. Just so you guys know what I'm trying to do, it doesn't have to be a login kinda thing. There is a variable that is passed through multiple functions and changes value in the script. I want to see what the variable's value is.

Answer (score 0):

i think calling the variable name or window.variableName should be enough to get any variable.

1. You can call it after an event or use setTimeOut to check at intervals